# Calling a running C# application from VBA

Tags: c#, .net, vba, com, interop

I have some VBA code that needs to talk to a running c# application.
For what it's worth, the c# application runs as a service, and exposes an interface via .net remoting.

I posted a question regarding a specific problem I'm having already ([From VB6 to .net via COM and Remoting...What a mess!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556163/from-vb6-to-net-via-com-and-remoting-what-a-mess)) but I think I may have my structure all wrong...

So I'm taking a step back - what's the best way to go about doing this?
One thing that's worth taking into account is that I want to call into the running application - not just call a precompiled DLL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution using my original structure...

That is, the VBA application calls a COM wrapper application that translates all of the types from .Net to COM safe types. This wrapper then calls the main service using .net remoting.

The problem I was having was that the common dlls between the wrapper and the service needed to be in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12 folder (along side msaccess.exe).

While I was using the AssemblyResolve method to provide the dlls at runtime, this wasn't working...So for now I'll just have to have the dlls copied to the folder - a far from elegant solution, but at least the communication is working for now.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, one way I accomplished something similar was with [Microsoft Message Queueing](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/msmq/default.mspx). Both languages/platforms can read/write to a queue.

In my scenario, we had a legacy Access database that we had to maintain. We wanted to migrate away from it and replace it with a more robust .NET solution. To get real time data out of the current system into the new system, we added VBA code to write data to a message queue. Then we wrote a C# windows service to process that data in the new system.

I'm not entirely sure of what you're doing, so this may not be a fit, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Hey - thanks for your suggestion. Unless there is no other way, I'd rather not have to write/maintain any VBA code. For this solution, I would have to define a bunch of message types, and write some code on both ends (c# & vba) that would pack/unpack the messages.